# DirectX11 with Clang shows black texture (with Visual Studio it works)

Tags: c++, clang, directx-11, directxtk

Hearing great things about Clang, I decided to give it a chance and installed Clang on my windows. With the installation it got integrated to my VisualStudo2015 too. Everything worked fine, until I tried to compile a small DirectX11 programm with clang.
First Clang got some problems with the "DirectXMath"-Headers of DirectX11. While DirectX treated the __m128 SIMD type as a union, clang used an float array. I decied to remove the clang headers and gaved the compiler only the microsoft headers. It compiled without any warning or error.
But when I started the programm, I just saw a black texture with the correct size and in the right position. Recompiling the programm with the normal VisualStudio-Compiler resolved in displaying the texture correctly, so I guess my code is correct.

Could there be any way to help Clang? I want to work more with Clang under Windows, but I don't want to change my project idea.

Some informations (which maybe could help):
1.) I'm using clang-cl with the following additional commands: -fms-compatibility -fms-extensions -Qunused-arguments
 
2.) I'm using the Windows 8.1 headers
3.) Drawing the texture is done with DirectXTK

Answer (score 0):

The basic SSE intrinsics syntax is defined by Intel, but the specifics of how the platform types `__m128` are implemented varies from compiler-to-compiler. It sounds like the problem is the few places where I have to use `V.m128_f32[i];` indexing in DirectXMath. It looks like newer version of Clang should work if this is `V[i]`.

I suspect you'll have to build everything with the preprocessor symbol `_XM_NO_INTRINSICS_` defined if Clang won't build with DirectXMath. I doubt that Visual C++ intrinsics headers will work properly with Clang.

> I've not personally tried to work with Clang, but if there are things I can do to improve [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) or [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) usage with Clang, let me know. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/issues/43) to track this particular problem.
>
> That said, Windows SDK headers are not fully Clang-compatible and certainly not in the Windows 8.1 SDK version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using the Visual C++ intrinsics. They compile fine. The problem is with the texture.
The position of the texture is passed with SSE and the position is correct. But the texture will be rendered black. The adress of the texture is correct too.